# Why, in Model.full_clean, is clean_fields called before clean?

Tags: django, django-models

Is there a reason, in `Model.full_clean`, for `clean_fields` be called before `clean`?
In my project, it would be more reasonable if I could first do my validations to then validate `clean_fields` stuff, like in this situation:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    status = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=False)

    def clean(self):
        if not self.status:
            self.status = 0
```

Would be any problem changing this ordering in `full_clean`?

Answer (score 8):

Why would it be "more reasonable"? As it's name describes, `clean_fields` is designed to clean each field individually, whereas the purpose of `clean` is only to validate field interactions. For example, one field can be blank only if another field is set, etc. The `clean_fields` method is called first to ensure that you can actually validate these interactions; if the fields have errors in general, it's pointless to validate them in conjunction.

Comment: but if you declare a field as not null, it will raise exception before you can run `clean` to validate field interactions.

Comment: That's not the purpose of clean. If you want to provide a default value, use the `default` kwarg, e.g. `status = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=False, default=0)`